# Is it possible to show a log of database queries in AdonisJs?

Tags: javascript, knex.js, adonis.js

Ruby on Rails allows seeing a log of the queries made to the database in all environments (dev, test, production). Is there a way one can replicate such functionality in Adonis.js?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about older versions of Adonis, but in **4** you can set **debug** option to `true` in your **config/database.js**:

```
mysql: {
  client: 'mysql2',
  connection: {
    ...
  },
  debug: true // here!
},
```

More here: https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/database#_debugging

Answer (score 1):

Running tests with `$ DEBUG=knex* yarn test` will display information about the queries being made.